# Как получить список всех сложных объектов в таблице Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Есть метод который получает объект `Poropose` вместе с объектом `User` на полях (`User` и `Poropose` объект в разных таблицах).

```
public Propose getProposeId(final int id) {
    Propose result;
    try (final Session session = factory.get().openSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        result = session.get(Propose.class, id);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Мне понадобилось в таком же духе получить список всех `Poropose`

```
select p from Propose p where p.id > 0
```

Так как get() требует предоставлять id объекта а мне нужны все то я попытался сделать так:

```
public List<Propose> getAllProposes() {

    List<Propose> result;
    final String query = "select p from Propose p where p.id > 0";

    try (final Session session = factory.get().openSession()) {

        final Query<Propose> id = session.createQuery(query, Propose.class);

        final Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        result = id.getResultList();
        transaction.commit();
    }
    return result;
}
```

При попытке вызвать этот код вот таким образом:

```
final SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
        .configure()
        .buildSessionFactory();

final List<Propose> allProposes = new DAOImp(new AtomicReference<>(factory))
        .getAllProposes();

factory.close();
System.out.println(allProposes.get(0));
```

Падает ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:
>   could not initialize proxy - no Session

Причем ругается на строку `factory.close();` и перекрытый `toString()` у `Proposes` где я распечатываю автора. Получается транзакция еще идет...

Как мне получить список всех объектов в таблице так чтобы Hibernate сам сделал подзапросы?

Составной объект Propose :

```
public class Propose implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private User auhtor;
    private boolean sold;
    private String description;
    private String mark;
    private String model;
    public Propose() {
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Propose{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", auhtor=" + auhtor +
            ", sold=" + sold +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", mark='" + mark + '\'' +
            ", model='" + model + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    ...гетеры сеттеры...
}
```

Его мапинг:

```
<class name="ru.pravvich.model.Propose" table="propose">

    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="sold" column="sold"/>
    <property name="description" column="description"/>
    <property name="mark" column="mark"/>
    <property name="model" column="model"/>

    <many-to-one name="auhtor"
                 column ="id_auhtor"
                 class="ru.pravvich.model.User">
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

У него на полях есть поле `User auhtor` которые хранятся в отдельной таблице, объект выглядит так:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    public User() {
    }
    ...гетеры сеттеры...
}
```

Мапинг:

```
<class name="ru.pravvich.model.User" table="users">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="login" column="login"/>
    <property name="password" column="password"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо измените код так, чтобы на момент обращения к `author` сессия была открыта, либо пропишите в маппинге отношения `Lazy="false"`, либо сделайте выборку жадной `select p from Propose p join fetch p.author where p.id > 0`.

Comment: жадная выборка бросает такой эксепшн: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: author of: ru.pravvich.model.Propose [select p from ru.pravvich.model.Propose p join fetch p.author where p.id > 0]` и указывает на строку `session.createQuery(query, Propose.class)`

Comment: Потому, что у вас опечатка - auhtor.